# Clear cache on AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am doing testing against AWS Redshift, and to replicate real world scenarios I need my test queries to not be cached so as not to give a false picture of performance. Is there any way for me to clear the Redshift cache between query runs?

Answer (score 13):

I believe you can disable the cache for the testing sessions by setting the value `enable_result_cache_for_session` to `off`

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_enable_result_cache_for_session.html)

> If enable_result_cache_for_session is off, Amazon Redshift ignores the results cache and executes all queries when they are submitted.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I had a query where first time it would run in 36s and subsequent runs would be <1s. Using this advice I ran this query first in my session `SET enable_result_cache_for_session = FALSE;` and then subsequent runs took about 10s. In real world usage this query can take between  12 and 40s , but that includes queue wait times and impact from other queries running on the cluster. Using time alone is not great for performance optimization though, bad operators in the query plan (dists, bcasts) have a big impact on concurrency.

Comment: Where do I have to enter this value? Do I set this when I start the custer?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know - you can't.
But for performance reasons and 'real world performance', as you mentioned, you should simply discard initial runs and use performance indicators from subsequent runs against warm cache. That sounds more real world than running against cold cache, which gives you worst case scenario.
If you insist on measuring cold cache performance, the simplest (although time consuming) solution is to reboot cluster after every cold run.

Comment: According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-query-performance.html  rebooting wouldn't work either. "The LRU cache persists through cluster reboots, but is wiped by maintenance upgrades."  But you're right about using warm cache because "the performance of a query the first time you run it can be misleading. You should always run a query a second time to determine its typical performance."

Comment: But in reality many apps are going to run a slew of different queries. Too many for LRU cache to handle. So eventually LRU cache is going to kick out some cache elements to make way for the new ones. Then you're right back to 'cold' query performance. It's important to always try to improve performance your slowest 'cold' query because it will happen again to the end user.

Comment: I created a new cluster from a snapshot - I'm now the only user. If I run a particular query, first time it takes ~36, if I run it again it's  less than 1s, so it is clearly just returning data from cache and not really running the query. That's not a real world measurement, the cache is not just warm; it's red hot. Ignoring the execution plan compilation time is not significant in this scenario. Performance profiling in a concurrent+parallel context is tricky :/