# How do I clear the cache in AWS Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

The question was answered here: [Clear cache on AWS Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039150/clear-cache-on-aws-redshift)

> I believe you can disable the cache for the testing sessions by setting the value `enable_result_cache_for_session` to off.

Since I am new to AWS Redshift I have no idea where I can enter this value. Could someone help me?

Do I have to configure this on startup or can I change it in a running cluster?

Comment: As per linked answer, run `SET enable_result_cache_for_session TO OFF` where you would normally run an SQL query in Redshift.

Comment: Thank you @JohnRotenstein. Could you please write this as an answer so I can close this question?

Comment: The question is already closed as a duplicate.